# Proof that $A^{-1} + A = 0$ holds only for $n \times n$ matrices, with n even

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix, then:
$A^{-1} + A = 0$ holds only for $n$ even.

How can I proof that the above holds?

Comment: $A^{-1} + A = 0$ doesn't hold in general for any dimension. On the other hand, there could definitely exist $A$ such that $A^{-1} + A = 0$ (such as a $90^\circ$ rotation of the plane), and whether such an $A$ exists could definitely depend on dimension. This means that your question, instead of "Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, then: $A^{-1} + A = 0$ holds only for $n$ even.", should have been something like "There exists an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that: $A^{-1} + A = 0$ only if $n$ is even." These things make a big difference.

Comment: (cont.) Althogh... It's not technically incorrect, since "only for" is not the same as "exactly when". It just sounds strange, and is easily misunderstood by people like me who do not read every sentence carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DonAntonio hinted:
$$
\det A^{-1} =  (\det A)^{-1} = \det (-A) = (-1)^n \det A
$$

Now, $\det A$ and $(\det A)^{-1}$ have the same sign (and are non zero since $A$ is invertible) so $(-1)^n \geq 0$ and $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Observe that from the given equality we have

$$\left(\det A\right)^{-1}=\det A^{-1}=\det(-A)\ldots$$

Comment: Did you mean $(-1)^n\det(A)$ hence the result?

Comment: @BillO'Haran Well, no: I meant what I've just edited now and meant the OP to complete using that, of course.